# Rails add association (has_many through) for each record in array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

I have a `task` model that has many `groups_belonging_to` through another table (task_group_relationships):

```
has_many :task_group_relationships, class_name: "TaskGroupRelationship",
                          foreign_key: "task_id",
                          dependent: :destroy
has_many :groups_belonging_to, through: :task_group_relationships, source: :task_group
```

When adding associations to each record in an array of tasks, I know I can do this:

```
tasks.each do |task|
    task.groups_belonging_to << task_group
end
```

But is there any way to add the associations all at once to save multiple calls to the DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just googled and found [this post](https://www.coffeepowered.net/2009/01/23/mass-inserting-data-in-rails-without-killing-your-performance/), it is pretty helpful.

So wrapping your inserts with a transaction should help. Something like this:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  tasks.each do |task|
      task.groups_belonging_to << task_group
  end
end
```

Comment: I hadn't really thought about this as a mass insert problem, but you are right that's really what it is as it is inserting new records into the `TaskGroupRelationship` table.